# Calling the right API endpoint on calendar click in SvelteKit

Tags: web-applications, svelte, sveltekit

I am using [this](https://github.com/6eDesign/svelte-calendar) calendar component in my Sveltekit project.
I have bound the variable to get updated when a date on the calendar is selected:

+page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { InlineCalendar } from 'svelte-calendar'
  import StatCard from '$lib/components/StatCard.svelte';
  
  export let data

  let selectedDate = new Date()
  const { incompleteEvents } = data

</script>

<InlineCalendar bind:selected={selectedDate} {theme} />
```

However, I want to display only those events that are applicable to the selected date listed on the page:

```
{#each incompleteEvents as event}
    <li>
      <a href="/admin">
        <span>{event.title}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
 {/each}
```

At this point when I log the selectedDate, it updates correctly on the calendar click on various dates.

I want to call the API using the selected date on the calendar something like this.

+page.server.ts

```js
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ fetch }) => {
    
    const getAllEvents = async () => {
        try {
            const allEventsResponse = await fetch(`/api/events/date=${selectedDate} `);
            const allEvents = await allEventsResponse.json();
        
              return allEvents;
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Failed to fetch all events:", error);
              return []; // Return a default value or appropriate error response
            }
        
        };
    
    //.... I have more code here that calls the function above and eventually returns the incomplete events
    
    return {
        incompleteEvents,
    }
}
```

However, I don't have access to the selectedDate in +page.server.ts and this code doesn't work.

Could someone help me achieve this? Maybe I'm on the wrong track altogether.
I want to hit the api endpoint with the date selected on the calendar (in +page.svelte) and only return those events.

I tried to write the code above and I tried calling the API with the selected date but I don't have access to it.